# failure to import geopy in jupyter notebook after using pipenv install

Tags: python, virtualenv, geopy, pipenv

I am using pipenv to install packages and create my virtual environment within my project repo. I am able to install geopy and confirm its installation using `pipenv graph`, but when I go into my `pipenv shell` and open jupyter notebook and try to import geopy I get `ImportError: No module named geopy`. I can only get geopy to import by running `! pip install geopy` within a jupyter notebook cell. Any ideas why jupyter notebook is not recognizing my pipenv install of geopy?

Comment: How do you start the notebook? You're probably starting it using a Python executable that is not used by the virtual environment.

Comment: within the pipenv shell I run `jupyter notebook`. I was able to get geopy to import within jupyter notebook by specifying the specific version of geopy, so I went and did that for my `haversine` import as well but now I am not able to import `haversine` within my jupyter notebook cell.

Answer (score 0):

OK I had a bit of a headache with this as I was doing a training program and the guy who was showing did not have it accurate.

Here are some links and suggestions to try to fix. I was using Anaconda for the Jupyter Notebook.

From "https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/pqFuJBDcBb4" one of the last comments had the command.

So just open Anaconda CLI prompt as Administrator.

```
conda install -c conda-forge geopy
```

Once you have done that you have to ensure you are using the right syntax as some of it has changed from the "tutorials" out there. Here is a great explanation: https://github.com/geopy/geopy

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="My_geolocate")

lookingFor = "Moscow"
locations = geolocator.geocode(lookingFor)

print(locations)
```

RESULTS:

Locating Moscow

Москва, Центральный федеральный округ, Россия

If you want returned location in English:

```
locations = geolocator.geocode(lookingFor, language="en")
```

References: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/geopy https://github.com/geopy/geopy